# EXCEL VBA formula error with sheet reference

Tags: vba, excel

Could someone please identify where the error is?

```
Sub calc_external_sales()
    Sheets("Monetary All").[C5].Formula = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;""bezahlt"")"
End Sub
```

I guess it has to do with the sheets and the range.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps

```
Sub calc_external_sales()
    Sheets("Monetary All").[C5].Formula = "=SUMIF(Rawdata!K2:K3446,Rawdata!I2:I3446,""bezahlt"")"
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub calc_external_sales()
    Sheets("Monetary All").[C5].FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;""bezahlt"")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are using the quotes around your search criteria ("bezahlt"), it is effectively treating it as two strings that are adjacent to each other with no concatenation. Use this instead:

```
Sub calc_external_sales()
    Sheets("Monetary All").[C5].Formula = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446,Rawdata!I2:I3446," & Chr(34) & "bezahlt" & Chr(34) & ")"
End Sub
```

The chr(34) is the symbol for quotation marks.