# Add formula to cell error

Tags: vba, excel

I've got this problem and it's driving me crazy. Probably easy to fix, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have this code to create a new worksheet based on another worksheet in a workbook.

Copying the worksheet is not a problem, but I also need to add this sheet into an overview sheet, where I use a formula to see whether the sheet is active or not.

This is the code:

```
'Create new worksheet
Sheets("Leeway").Copy after:=Sheets("Leeway")
Set WS = ActiveSheet
WS.Name = "Leeway " & ddCountries.Value

'Add new worksheet to Control sheet
Dim c As Range
Set c = Sheets("Control Sheet").Range("H5")
Do Until c.Value = ""
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

c.Value = WS.Name
c.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IF('" & WS.Name & "'!L42<>"""";""Active"";""Inactive"")"
```

At the last line, where the formula is added gives the following error: "1004: Application-defined or object-defined error".

I've added this formula to the watch and (I'm pretty sure that) it gives the correct formula.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Also possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459394/excel-vba-formula-error-1004?s=2|3.1671) and [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958099/excel-vba-formula-error-with-sheet-reference?s=3|2.3860) and [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315422/excel-vba-formula-function?s=9|1.3983) and there are more :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in VBA code you have to use `,` instead of `;` for a `.Formula` to be put into a cell

Comment: Yes, you're awesome! I knew it was easy to fix, just didn't know where to find the error. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you need double quotes around the active and inactive, use  "=IF(" & ws.name & "!L42<>" & """" & """" & "," & """" & "Active" & """" & "," & """" & "Inactive" & """" & ")"

Comment: @MatthewD and change `;` to `,` ;) but, the qoutes as done by RobK are correct.

Comment: Oh yeah, Right..  I was looking at the string format and missed the obvious.

Comment: You were so quick that I wasn't allowed to accept the answer yet - I have no idea why there is a time lock on that. Anyway, I've accepted your answer now. And thanks for your comment MatthewD, but my problem is already solved in a cleaner way.

Comment: Its probably there to allow other users to also provide an anwser.